# Cannot execute the app directly on phone

Tags: android, exception, permissions

Hi i have developed an app which i am trying to run directly on an android 2.2 phone but i am getting the following error.

```
01-30 16:55:10.450: E/AndroidRuntime(16550): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{org.fluturasymphony.recommendation/org.fluturasymphony.recommendation.ActivityList}: java.lang.SecurityException: ConnectivityService: Neither user 10051 nor current process has android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE.
```

For full [error log](http://pastebin.com/g88bm0XM) see here.

Comment: Have you added android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE to the manifest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as in log :

> Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: ConnectivityService: Neither
>   user 10051 nor current process has
>   android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE.

means you will need to add `android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE` permission in `AndroidManifest.xml`

**EDIT :**

add permission as in manifest :

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <!-- add permission -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application>
    <!-- Appliction components -->
    <!-- ----- -->
    </application>

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="1" />

    </manifest>
```

Comment: can you tell me how to add the permission?